# Building a neural network that takes a created feature vector

Tags: python, tensorflow, feature-extraction, word-embedding

To be more precise. Lets say I already have a vector that represents something (word, object, image...) and that I can not change the way I get it. What I would like to do is create a NN without the embedding and pooling layer and am wondering if tensorflow supports this kind of aproach.

Lets say my vector is 10 features long (10 floats). For each vector I also have a label, lets say there are 3 labels to chose from.

What I am (struggling/trying) to do is this. I would like to push this sort of vector input into a keras dense layer with relu activation and 10 neurons (stack maybe 2 or 3) and then as a final layer use sigmoid activation with 3 output neurons.

Then fit with labels on 40(?) epochs and so on...

My main question is well.. Is this possible? I have yet to finish the code and maybe I am asking this a bit too soon, but nevertheless. 
Is this how one would approach this or would you build the model from embedding layer down and would not use the already made vectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed it is possible.

One way to do it is to create a generator function yielding the vectors (that will do your vector representation, whatever it is) you want to pass to the network. Then create a TensorFlow dataset by calling [`tf.data.Dataset.from_generator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator).

The model will be then probably just a [`Sequential`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Sequential) of dense layers.

Comment: Thanks! Ill look into the mentioned generator and yes the model was ment to be Sequential of a few dense layers.